# FileNotFoundException: path (reason) - where can I find all possible "reason" messages?

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

Starting from Android 2.2, the FileNotFoundException contains additional information about problem:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /foo/bar (No such file or directory)
```

The error message format is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: path (reason)
```

I have seen such reasons:

- Invalid argument
- No space left on device
- No such file or directory
- Permission denied
- Read-only file system

**Q:** Where can I find all possible *reason* messages? Documentation, or the source file where they are thrown from.

Comment: Do you mean FileNotFoundException page? Yes, I did, nothing usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions like this are sort of generic, used by other classes, and will generally not contain the "reasons" that you mentioned.  Any class could use a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` exception, so in order to find all of the possible "reasons" you would need to search the Android source code for something like `throws FileNotFoundException` or `new FileNotFoundException`.